# Solve a PDE using characteristic equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Given $u_t - u u_{xx} - u_{xxx} = 0$
I am looking for solutions through the following vector:

\begin{equation}
-t \cosh(\omega x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \left( \cosh(\omega x) +2tu\sinh(\omega 
x) \right)\frac{\partial}{\partial u}
\end{equation}

The method is to find invariant solutions through Lie Symmetry.  What is written above is one such Symmetry.

The first invariant is automatically $y = t$

Now to find the second invariant: $v(y)$ I have to solve the characteristic:

\begin{equation}
\frac{-dx}{t \cosh(\omega x)} = \frac{du}{\cosh(\omega x) + 2tu \sinh(\omega x))}
\end{equation}

having two terms in the denominator with one of them having a $u$ is what is throwing me off.
How would I solve this?

Comment: Thank you @mattos I have added more background. Basically I wanted to know a method to solving the differential equation given at the end of the question.